# How to get shared calendar list using caldav4j from davical?

Tags: java, caldav

I created my own calendar using netbeans, caldav4j and Davical. However, I can't get shared calendar list.

I can create a calendar or an event. I can see them at Agendav. But when I share calendar to other users at Agendav, I can't get it with my netbeans code.

I want to show which user shared calendar with me.

```
    HttpClient http = createHttpClient();
    HostConfiguration hostConfig = createHostConfiguration();

    PropFindMethod propfind = new PropFindMethod();
    propfind.setPath(caldavCredential.home);

    PropProperty propFindTag = PropertyFactory.createProperty(PropertyFactory.PROPFIND);
    PropProperty aclTag = PropertyFactory.createProperty(PropertyFactory.ACL);
    PropProperty propTag = new PropProperty(CalDAVConstants.NS_DAV,"D","prop");
    propTag.addChild(aclTag);
    propFindTag.addChild(propTag);
    propfind.setPropFindRequest(propFindTag);
    propfind.setDepth(0);

    executeMethod(hostConfig, propfind);

    Set<String> keySet = (propfind.getResponseHashtable()).keySet();
    for(String key: keySet){
       CalDAVResponse response =  (propfind.getResponseHashtable()).get(key);
       String href = response.getHref();

       Ace[] aces = propfind.getAces(href);
       Enumeration enumerations = aces.enumeratePriviliges();
       while(enumerations.hasMoreElements()){
           Privilege privilege = (Privilege)enumerations.nextElement();
           System.out.println("parameter: " + privilege.getParameter());
       }
    }
```

I try to get privileges but there is no parameter. I only want which user shared calendars with me. I can make calendar, add event but I can't access shared calendar list.

Comment: You should show some code. It is hard to help you without.

Comment: How does caldav4j find shared users? I want a basic question, but I'm new to it and I couldn't find anything. Where can I find this user if a user has shared his calendar with me?